# Deleting part of variable String in php

Tags: php

I have the function `get_price_data();` which gives **"*0,11\u20ac*"** as return value.

The **"*0,11*"** is not static. 
I want to do some maths with ***"0,11"*** from the string below.

My Code shown down below does not work how i want it to. Has someone any idea how i can complete this task ? I am very new to php.

```
<?php 
function get_price_data() {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Chroma%202%20Case");
    $decode = json_decode($json,1);
    echo $decode['median_price'];
}

$string=get_price_data();
$string2 = str_replace("\u20ac","",$string);
echo $string2 * 1000 - 120;
?>
```

Comment: is 0,11 two values(eg. 0 & 11)  or one(eg. 0.11)?  also are they supposed to be integers?

Comment: in germany 0,11 is like your 0.11 ... Sry should have said that before. So this is one value. I dont know if you need to convert that it to an integer.

Comment: echo floatval(str_replace(',','.',$string));  returns 0.11  (where $string="0,11\u20ac").    This will work as long as your number in $string is followed by some non-numeric value (such as €)

Comment: @KorreyD it does not work for me. I tried exactly this .. CTRL + C and it just returns "0,11€0"...

Comment: hmm floatval(str_replace(',','.',"0,11\u20ac")); could not possibly return "0,11€0" because "0,11€0" is a string.  worse case if it was "not working"  floatval() would return a 0

Comment: The script is echoing "0,11€0"... did you try it on your own ?

Comment: looks like you were getting "0,11€" printed out every time because you had an echo at the end of your function there, instead of actually returning the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
function get_price_data() {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=Chroma%202%20Case");
    $decode = json_decode($json,1);
    return $decode['median_price'];  // return here instead of echo.
}
```

You are somewhat correct that this `return` is necessary because this is a function. A `return` statement is not specifically required in a PHP function (functions will return `null` by default if there is no explicit return value.) The reason you need it to return is that you are using its returned value in this statement:

```
$string=get_price_data();
```

With `echo` instead of `return`, `$string` will be set to `null` here, and any subsequent operations on it will obviously not do what you intended.

If you change your function to `return` the value of `$decode['median_price']`, then `$string=get_price_data();` will assign `0,11€` to `$string`, and then your replacements and calculations should work as expected.

```
$string=str_replace(array('€','\u20ac'),'',$string);
$string = str_replace(",",".",$string);  // replace , with . as noted by mertizci
echo $string * 1000 - 120;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the comma in the changed price value, PHP cant do math things on it. You should change the comma with dot too.

Your code should be (edited):

```
    <?php  
$string=get_price_data();
$string=str_replace(array('€','\u20ac'),'',$string);
$string = str_replace(",",".",$string);  
echo $string * 1000 - 120;
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this does not work for me. It will give you "0,11€-120".. thats not what i wanted :D

Comment: did it work for you ? i also updated the Code above. For me your new Code does not work either ... just copy and pasted it.

Comment: @LaurinM.Whats the returned result ?

Comment: @LaurinM.Edited again, can you try now with new code.